# Azure Active Directory Domain Controller

Tags: active-directory

Currently we have 7 domain controllers, 5 on premise and 2 on Azure environment. The domain controller on premise hold 5 FSMO roles.

We're in the process of decomm. DC on premise. What step should I take to transfer the FSMO roles to the DC in Azure and promote to PDC then turn off the DCs on premise? We don't have any DHCP service on premise.

Thanks in advance for the help.

dtng

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that you have a site-to-site VPN or Express Route connection and that Name resolution is working then transferring roles between your on premise DCs and your Azure DCs is the same as transferring them between two different on premise DCs.

I would always make sure everything is backed up before starting the process then follow a guide like....

http://scug.be/wim/2016/06/16/replica-dcs-on-azure-transferring-fsmo-roles-to-the-iaas-dcs/

Comment: Thanks for the link, Michael. We do have express route in place and DNS name resolution is working. Running test with "dcdiag /TEST:FSMOCHECK" from the DC in Azure, it passed. I noticed that Active Directory Sites and Services, the Default-First-Site-Name only show 5 DCs on premise. Should I add the 2 DCs in Azure? After FSMO roles transfered to Azure DC, can I promote Azure DC and turn off the DCs on premise

Comment: Hi, I would create a 2nd site in Sites and Services called something like "Azure Site" link the correct IP Subnets to it. When you install your new DCs in Azure make sure they are added to the new "Azure Site". If the DCs are already installed in Azure, then drag the DCs into your newly created site. once the Azure hosted DCs are in your newly created site give them a reboot or run Ipconfig /RegisterDNS on Each and stop and restart the Netlogon service on each then they should then be the go to DCs for any resources hosted in Azure.